# How do you find actual pixel width of percentage width

Tags: css, layout, width

How do you find the actual pixel width of a percentage width div how it is currently displayed in a browser or with a certain browser size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use jQuery

[$.width()](https://api.jquery.com/width/)

Comment: Is it possible to use CSS?

Comment: No, you have to use some sort of javascript.